# running codes simultaneously while outputting result one by one

Tags: concurrency

I have a scripts looks like:

```sh
for simplify in 0.1 ;do
  for lmbda in 0.9 1.1 1.3;do
    for mu in 2.1 3.4 4.2;do
      rm eci.out;
      csce.py --mu $mu --lmbda $lmbda --simplify $simplify  \
        --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable \
        --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat \
        --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat \
        --preserve-ground-state 100 
     done
   done
 done
```

While running sequentially, it will output

```
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.0002 --lmbda 0.005 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.0002,  lambda = 0.005,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.03952735        0.04380240        0.02230235       -0.00185235
    230 clusters      0.03734292        0.04294355        0.02049885       -0.00162721
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 13.8588
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.2201
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.0002 --lmbda 0.5 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.0002,  lambda = 0.5,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.04017143        0.04451601        0.02267050       -0.00188774
    219 clusters      0.03826959        0.04392544        0.02088397       -0.00166322
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 7.9875
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.1674
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.002 --lmbda 0.5 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.002,  lambda = 0.5,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.14367173        0.15893736        0.07206284       -0.00912716
    237 clusters      0.12351319        0.17167930        0.05376677       -0.00158861
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 5.4561
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.1119
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.002 --lmbda 0.005 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.002,  lambda = 0.005,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.14299857        0.15820042        0.07228279       -0.00898964
    237 clusters      0.12292319        0.17103283        0.05359447       -0.00138365
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 5.3224
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.1104
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.02 --lmbda 0.5 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.02,  lambda = 0.5,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.19027749        0.20991052        0.09677830       -0.01602039
    237 clusters      0.17531289        0.27618581        0.06910020        0.00220309
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 2.4223
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.0638
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.2 --lmbda 0.5 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.2,  lambda = 0.5,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.26328087        0.28804954        0.15654138       -0.03325137
    237 clusters      0.20897747        0.39607952        0.07887236        0.00877210
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 1.9517
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.0477
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.02 --lmbda 0.005 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.02,  lambda = 0.005,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.18831434        0.20789816        0.09380533       -0.01523797
    237 clusters      0.17809687        0.28067519        0.06919726        0.00308981
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 2.4420
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.0642
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.0002 --lmbda 0.05 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.0002,  lambda = 0.05,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.03972713        0.04402288        0.02232628       -0.00187813
    220 clusters      0.03735457        0.04295330        0.02008527       -0.00161760
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 9.9223
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.1863
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.2 --lmbda 0.005 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.2,  lambda = 0.005,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.23518508        0.25836295        0.13669345       -0.02483126
    237 clusters      0.21460451        0.36901059        0.08558721        0.00618068
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 1.7372
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.0490
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.002 --lmbda 0.05 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.002,  lambda = 0.05,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.14375418        0.15902969        0.07218794       -0.00912434
    237 clusters      0.12364959        0.17204399        0.05379933       -0.00144881
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 5.5220
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.1124
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
 /home1/03631/key01027/local_python_lib/bin/csce.py --mu 0.02 --lmbda 0.05 --simplify 0.1 --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat --preserve-ground-state 100
 Split-Bregman Input Parameters:  mu = 0.02,  lambda = 0.05,  eci_cutoff = 1e-08
 Attempting to simplify the CE using a target RMSE of 0.1
 Warning: Unable to achieve target RMSE of 0.1
                      RMSE              RMSE (no wght)    MAE               ME
    237 clusters      0.19066043        0.21033595        0.09672442       -0.01606650
    237 clusters      0.17565376        0.27643274        0.06917755        0.00238796
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. input   : 2.4257
   Leave-one-out CV score wrt. full fit: 0.0639
   Writing CV energies to file `cv-energies.dat'.
```

However, to make the computation more efficient, I know that we could run it simultaneously with "&":

```sh
for simplify in 0.1 ;do
  for lmbda in 0.9 1.1 1.3;do
    for mu in 2.1 3.4 4.2;do
      rm eci.out;
      csce.py --mu $mu --lmbda $lmbda --simplify $simplify  \
        --favor-low-energy 0.01 --bias-stable \
        --save-energies ce-energies.dat --save-weights ce-weights.dat \
        --casm-eci-file eci.in eci.out --save-hull ce-hull.dat \
        --preserve-ground-state 100 &
     done
   done
 done
```

But then its output would be chaotic... What could I do so that its output would be in sequence while running these concurrently? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you fork all those commands, the output to STDOUT won't be in order, since the forks won't run in order.

You can redirect all the `csce.py` calls to individual files and then tail those files. Use the loop variables for the file names to understand which file represents which process.

But for the sake of scalability and control, using [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) might be worth trying out.

By the way the names of the `*.dat` files do not depend on the parameters of your call, so depending on how the python script works, these might get clobbered (overwritten) or grow with every call to your script.

Answer (score 1):

yes gnu parallel will work out well but if you want to do it through & operator, you need to know that forked process will only run when it gets hold of the resouse, since resources are sharing the same stdout it would seem the output is chaotic.